# Is it possible to assert types dynamically in golang?

Tags: go, types, assertion, reflect

I have a method Deduplicate that returns deduplicated copy of passed in slice as an interface{}. Is there a way to cast returned by this method interface{} value to the same type as I passed in this method without writing it explicitly? For example, if I change myStruct.RelatedIDs type from []int to []uint it will prevent code from compiling.

https://play.golang.org/p/8OT4xYZuwEn

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type myStruct struct {
    ID         int
    RelatedIDs []int
}

func main() {
    s := &myStruct{
        ID:         42,
        RelatedIDs: []int{1, 1, 2, 3},
    }
    v, _ := Deduplicate(s.RelatedIDs)
    s.RelatedIDs = v.([]int) // << can I assert type dynamically here?
    // s.RelatedIDs = v.(reflect.TypeOf(s.RelatedIDs)) // does not work
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s.RelatedIDs)
}

func Deduplicate(slice interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    if reflect.TypeOf(slice).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("slice has wrong type: %T", slice)
    }

    s := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    res := reflect.MakeSlice(s.Type(), 0, s.Len())

    seen := make(map[interface{}]struct{})
    for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
        v := s.Index(i)
        if _, ok := seen[v.Interface()]; ok {
            continue
        }
        seen[v.Interface()] = struct{}{}
        res = reflect.Append(res, v)
    }

    return res.Interface(), nil
}
```

Comment: "can I assert type dynamically" no. Go is a statically-typed language.

Comment: Have `Deduplicate` work on pointer-to-slice, and do the re-assignment inside that function with `reflect`.

Comment: In a statically typed language, the idea of "asserting types dynamically" as implied here, doesn't mean anything and is therefore not possible. What you're really getting at here are "generic functions", which are not (yet) supported in Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type myStruct struct {
    ID         int
    RelatedIDs []int
}

func main() {
    s := &myStruct{
        ID:         42,
        RelatedIDs: []int{1, 1, 2, 3},
    }
    err := Deduplicate(&s.RelatedIDs)
    fmt.Println(err)
    // s.RelatedIDs = v.([]int) // << can I assert type dynamically here?
    // s.RelatedIDs = v.(reflect.TypeOf(s.RelatedIDs)) // does not work
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s.RelatedIDs)
}

func Deduplicate(slice interface{}) error {
    rts := reflect.TypeOf(slice)
    rtse := rts.Elem()
    if rts.Kind() != reflect.Ptr && rtse.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return fmt.Errorf("slice has wrong type: %T", slice)
    }

    rvs := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    rvse := rvs.Elem()

    seen := make(map[interface{}]struct{})
    var e int
    for i := 0; i < rvse.Len(); i++ {
        v := rvse.Index(i)
        if _, ok := seen[v.Interface()]; ok {
            continue
        }
        seen[v.Interface()] = struct{}{}
        rvse.Index(e).Set(v)
        e++
    }

    rvse.SetLen(e)
    rvs.Elem().Set(rvse)

    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hkEW4u1aGUi

with future generics, it might look like this https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/jobI5wKR8fU

Answer (score 2):

### Updated answer

Since Go 1.21, you can rely on [the `Compact` function](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Compact) from the `slices` package:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 1, 2, 3} // assumed sorted
    res := slices.Compact(s)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", res)
}
```

Output:

```
[]int{1, 2, 3}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0ybH-Bw9kI2))

And if the compacted slice is much shorter than the original one, you may want to pass it through [`slices.Clone`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Clone) in order to make the old (large) backing array (and its elements) eligible for GC.

### Original answer

For completeness, here is a generic version ([Playground](https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/FAsAjB2znkt)), which doesn't require reflection. Only open in [February 2022](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#Status)! The [usual caveats about `NaN`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20660) apply, though.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 1, 2, 3}
    res := Deduplicate(s)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", res)
}

func Deduplicate[T comparable](s []T) []T {
    seen := make(map[T]struct{})
    res := make([]T, 0, len(s))
    for _, elem := range s {
        if _, exists := seen[elem]; exists {
            continue
        }
        seen[elem] = struct{}{}
        res = append(res, elem)
    }
    return res
}
```

Output:

```
[]int{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: `Deduplicate[int](s)` can be written `Deduplicate(s)`. Really awesome.

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks! That wasn't the case last time I checked; the Go team must have improved the type-inference algorithm. I too am looking forward to generics, if only because less reflection will be needed.